# Unset QStyle from widget

Tags: c++, qt5

How I can unset a QStyle from widget and restore is QStyle to default?

```
class MyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    int styleHint(QStyle::StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption* option = 0,
                  const QWidget* widget = 0, QStyleHintReturn* returnData = 0) const
    {
        if (hint == SH_Slider_AbsoluteSetButtons)
            return (Qt::LeftButton | Qt::MidButton | Qt::RightButton);
        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
    }

};

myWidget->setStyle(new MyStyle(myWidget->style()));
```

Comment: How about saving its style before you change it? Then you can restore it to whatever it was.

Comment: How can I get the style before change?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? There is, for example, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#style